# Does permanent residence for AUS/NZ require 'renewals'?

Tags: australia, new-zealand

I read the AUS/NZ permanent residence is infinite. Other countries require perm to be renewed after 5 years or so.

1) Is it same for AUS/NZ?

2) Is it same for minors too ?

Comment: Do you have an example of a country that requires permanent residence to be renewed?  Such a requirement seems antithetical to the nature of permanence.

Comment: @phoog Czech Republic requires its permanent residencies to be renewed once every 10 years, although the documentation required to do so is minimal.

Comment: @JonathanReez what happens if the permanent resident fails to renew?  Does the person lose the right to remain in the country?

Comment: @phoog you're right. I've double checked the law and non-extension of the residency card does not lead to losing the permanent residency.

Answer (score 2):

Australian permanent visas do not need to be renewed, as long as you remain in Australia and do not travel overseas.

However, if you do travel overseas, there is a limit in terms of a "travel facility".  From the Department's [web site](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/permanent-resident/overseas-travel):

> When you are granted a permanent visa, you are usually permitted a 5-year travel facility. This means you can leave and re-enter Australia as many times as you like in the 5 years from the date your permanent visa was granted, as long as your visa remains valid.
>
> After 5 years, your travel facility expires and you will need to apply for, and be granted:
>
> - a Resident Return visa - if you wish to re-enter Australia as a permanent resident or
> - Australian citizenship - if you wish to travel as an Australian citizen.